# How to Block multiple request from same IP address?

Tags: tomcat, java, google-cloud-platform, jmeter

I have a java application which is running in Tomcat server. I was trying to load test of my application with Jmeter. While I put a load of more than 100 users, the CPU utilization increases drastically and also the server becomes unresponsive. How to prevent, In case there is an intentional unauthorized load test on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 possible ways to achieve this in GCP:

a) Firewall rules will help you to control incoming and outgoing traffic from your network. Using [Firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) allows you to deny unauthorized traffic to reach your server, to do this, you can configure an ingress firewall rule to only allow traffic from specific IP address within your VPC network.

b) In order to add more protection you can use [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/) and [HTTPs Load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/). HTTP(S) Load Balancing mitigates and absorbs many Layer 4 and below attacks, such as SYN floods, IP fragment floods, port exhaustion, etc. While Cloud armor is designed to protect your services against denial of service (DDoS) and web attacks.